# ScalaJS Project: SBT dependency on Leaflet not resolved

Tags: intellij-idea, leaflet, scala.js

I have a ScalaJS project built in IntelliJ with SBT in which I'd like to include a slippy map based on the Leaflet library.

I'm using ScalaJS version 0.6.19 and SBT version 0.13.7

My `build.sbt` is the following:

```
import com.lihaoyi.workbench.Plugin.{bootSnippet, updateBrowsers}

enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)

workbenchSettings

name := "WeatherReport"
version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "org.scala-js"    %%% "scalajs-dom"       % "0.9.1"
  ,"org.scala-js"    %%% "scalajs-java-time" % "0.2.2"
  ,"com.lihaoyi"     %%% "scalatags"         % "0.6.5"
  ,"org.webjars.npm" %%% "leaflet"           % "0.7.7"
)

bootSnippet := "com.sap.demo.WeatherReport().main(document.getElementById('weatherDiv'));"

updateBrowsers <<= updateBrowsers.triggeredBy(fastOptJS in Compile)
```

This was all working fine until I added the last dependency on `leaflet`.  Now SBT complains:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:
...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-util;8.1.16.v20140903 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-io;8.1.16.v20140903 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-http;8.1.16.v20140903 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-server;8.1.16.v20140903 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-continuation;8.1.16.v20140903 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.webjars.npm#leaflet_sjs0.6_2.11;0.7.7: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.webjars.npm:leaflet_sjs0.6_2.11:0.7.7 (/Developer/Scala/weather-report/build.sbt#L13-19)
[warn]        +- weatherreport:weatherreport_sjs0.6_2.11:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.webjars.npm#leaflet_sjs0.6_2.11;0.7.7: not found
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.webjars.npm#leaflet_sjs0.6_2.11;0.7.7: not found
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 31-Aug-2017 10:26:54
```

As fas a I can tell from the [leaflet entry](http://www.webjars.org/all) on the WebJars website, I've got the group/artifact/version information correct.

I'm not clear on why the error message has added "_sjs0.6_2.11" to the library name.  Is this because there needs to be some version of leaflet specific to ScalaJS?

Thanks

Chris W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are confusing [Webjars](http://www.webjars.org/), which are .jars containing .js libraries published on Maven, with Scala.js libraries, which also .jars published on Maven, but containing Scala.js' .sjsir files.

Depending on the JS libraries in Webjars is typically done with [`jsDependencies`](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/dependencies.html) in a Scala.js sbt build, *not* with `libraryDependencies`. Therefore, they should also use `%` instead of `%%%`. For example:

```
jsDependencies += "org.webjars.npm" % "leaflet" % "0.7.7" / "dist/leaflet.js"
```

Now you will probably also want Scala.js facades to talk to Leaflet using static types. Fortunately for you, [such a facade library already exists](https://github.com/fancellu/scalajs-leaflet). Since a facade library is a Scala.js library (as opposed to a JS library in a Webjar), that would be specified in `libraryDependencies`, with `%%%`. However it seems that that particular library is not (yet) published on Maven Central, so you might have to locally publish it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I'm still missing something here.

Now that I've added the jsDependencies line, I get another error message saying:

    [warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
    [warn]   org.webjars.npm:leaflet:0.7.7 
((org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal) ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala#L996)
    [warn]     +- weatherreport:weatherreport_sjs0.6_2.11:0.1-SNAPSHOT

However, the pom file for Leaflet exists in Maven https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/webjars/npm/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet-0.7.7.pom

Comment: Nope, sorry.  It was a proxy problem in (not-so-)IntelliJ.  If I disconnect from my corporate VPN and set IntelliJ to no-proxy, then it works...

Grrrr